# Play an MP3 clip from a Facebook app

Tags: flash, api, facebook, multimedia

I have a Facebook app named "Rails Across Europe" I would like to add some multimedia to it. I want to play a short MP3 sound clip every time the player's train reaches a city. Each city will have it's own unique sound clip. Problem is, I have no idea how to do this from the Facebook API. I suspect it involves using the Flash player. Anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/mp3

Comment: Thanks. That would be perfect, except that I just discovered that my audio editor only allows me to save clips in WAV format. Do you know if Facebook supports WAV?

Comment: The only audio format that it supports is MP3. Though there are several converters that will convert a WAV file into an MP3 file.

Comment: Actually, I purchased the Pro package that lets me save in MP3, now I'm set! Thanks! (I did try to find the FB docs, but FB dev kept redirecting me to a "github" site and there were no docs that I could find :/)